# Preloading Doctrine ODM referenced documents

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine ODM (MongoDB) and I have something like the following

- `Attendee` document
- `Answer` document
- each `Answer` references one `Attendee`. (one-to-many relation)

I do something like the following

```
attendees = attendeeRepo.findby(whatever)

foreach(attendees as attendee)
    answers = attendee.getAnswers()
```

The problem here is that on each `attendee.getAnswers()` Doctrine ODM executes a query like that:

```
db.TicketAnswer.find({ 
    "attendee.$id": ObjectId("50ae80608ead0ea71e00008b") 
})
```

if I have 100 atendees, 100 queries like this one will get executed, so I was trying to preload all `Answers` before the loop. but it didn't work as I expected.

I guess it didn't work as I was expecting as this is a one-to-many relation and I asked the one side of the relation (`Attendee`) to load the many (`Answer`). in other cases when I'm doing the opposite, preloading works as expected.

I'm not sure what's the best solution for a case like that. wish if anyone has ideas that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article out:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html

To quote:

```
/** @Document */
class User
{
    /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account") */
    private $accounts;
}
```

-

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')
    ->field('accounts')->prime(true)
    ->limit(100);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$users = $query->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, but tried it before. it only works for the case you mentioned `@ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account")` 

but doesn't work for `@ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account", mappedBy="user")`